# Q: Duplicate any character using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to duplicate any character using regex,
my regex is like this.

Test String:`(.+\n)`

Regex101 https://regex101.com/r/zE7wF7/1

Ouput:

```
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
24.5
44.5
44.5
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
36
```

Comment: Whats your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate any character, just group the character you're searching for and replace it with two copies:

```
/(a)/\1\1/g
```

will turn `"abracadabra"` into `"aabraacaadaabraa"`

If you want to duplicate EACH character, you can just do it on `.`:

```
/(.)/\1\1/g
```

will turn `"abracadabra"` into `"aabbrraaccaaddaabbrraa"`

If you only want to duplicate the last character of the line, put the other part of your test outside your group:

```
/(.)$/\1\1/mg
```

will turn

```
abracadabra
alakazam
```

into

```
abracadabraa
alakazamm
```